# React Router: TypeError: oldElement._store is undefined

Tags: reactjs, react-router

Trying to take an existing app and use React Router with the simplest HashLocation method to get started.

Using:
React 0.12.2
React Router 0.12.4

**main.js (entry point):**

```
// Create App Container
$('body').prepend('<div id="appContainer"></div>');

// Run the App
Router.run(Routes, function (Handler) {
  React.render(React.createElement(Handler), document.getElementById('appContainer'));
});
```

**routes.jsx:**

```
var React = require('react'),
    Router = require('react-router'),
    Route = Router.Route,
    DefaultRoute = Router.DefaultRoute,

    App = require('./app'),
    Question1 = require('./views/question1'),
    Question2 = require('./views/question2'),
    Question3 = require('./views/question3'),
    Question4 = require('./views/question4'),
    Question5 = require('./views/question5'),
    Question6 = require('./views/question6'),
    Question7 = require('./views/question7'),
    Result = require('./views/result');

var Routes = (
  <Route name="app" path="/" handler={App}>
    <Route name="questions/1" handler={Question1}/>
    <Route name="questions/2" handler={Question2}/>
    <Route name="questions/3" handler={Question3}/>
    <Route name="questions/4" handler={Question4}/>
    <Route name="questions/5" handler={Question5}/>
    <Route name="questions/6" handler={Question6}/>
    <Route name="questions/7" handler={Question6}/>
    <Route name="results" handler={Result}/>
    <DefaultRoute handler={Question1}/>
  </Route>
);

module.exports = Routes;
```

**app.jsx:**

```
var Router = require('react-router');
var Link = Router.Link;
var RouteHandler = Router.RouteHandler;

var App = React.createClass({
  render: function() {
    return (
      <section id='app' style={styles.app}>
        <header>
          <ul>
            <li><Link to="questions/1">Question 1</Link></li>
            <li><Link to="questions/2">Question 2</Link></li>
            <li><Link to="questions/3">Question 3</Link></li>
            <li><Link to="questions/4">Question 4</Link></li>
            <li><Link to="questions/5">Question 5</Link></li>
            <li><Link to="questions/6">Question 6</Link></li>
            <li><Link to="questions/7">Question 7</Link></li>
            <li><Link to="results">Results</Link></li>
          </ul>
        </header>

        <Router.RouteHandler/>

      </section>
    );
  }
});

module.exports = App;
```

**question1.jsx (other questions are like this too):**

```
var React = require('react');

var Question1 = React.createClass({
  render: function() {
    return (
      <div>
        Question 1.
      </div>
    );
  }
});

module.exports = Question1;
```

When I click any link rendered in app.jsx, Firefox's console displays this error:
[image]

Which takes me to this line in the built main.js file:
[image]

However, in Chrome, I get a completely different error: 
[image]

Funny thing is that if I refresh the entire page manually, the correct question appears on screen, for example if I open a new tab and go to http://localhost:9090/#/questions/1 it will show "Question 1" on the screen:
[image]

But, when I click on Question 2, this is what triggers the error:
[image]

But, if I reload the page entirely while at the questions/2 url, it will work:
[image: On Fresh Reload]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that using the global build (installed with Bower) fixed this right away.  This error is caused by using the NPM build instead of the global one.  In this error scenario, I was installing React Router from NPM, which returns the lib/index.js file, which at a glance looks right, but apparently there are issues using that export.

So, to remedy this, just run `bower install --save react-router` and if you're using browserify (or another bundler that supports CommonJS), update your package.json's browser field to include a shim for react-router in bower_components:

```
"browser": {
  ...
  "react-router": "./bower_components/react-router/build/global/ReactRouter.min.js"
}
```

UPDATE: Filed an issue on `react-router`'s Github: [Router breaks when using the NPM build of React Router](https://github.com/rackt/react-router/issues/903)

Answer (score 0):

My guess is duplicate React in `node_modules/react-router/node_modules/react` causing issues. If you delete it, NPM should work fine.

See also: https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/2402